# Django throwing ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) with no change to the code

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have written a new function in a subfolder and my django project that was running fine is now throwing the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\IndicatorAnalyserWebapp\Analyser\Indicators\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .views import (
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\IndicatorAnalyserWebapp\Analyser\Indicators\views.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .forms import IndicatorForm, SearchForIndicatorMetaData
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\IndicatorAnalyserWebapp\Analyser\Indicators\forms.py", line 24, in <module>
    class IndicatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 252, in __new__
    opts.field_classes)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 166, in fields_for_model
    formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1873, in formfield
    return super(IntegerField, self).formfield(**defaults)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 872, in formfield
    defaults['choices'] = self.get_choices(include_blank=include_blank)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 802, in get_choices
    for choice, __ in choices:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Similar questions have been asked in the past and it has always been that someone has used a dictionary rather than an iterable to define choices. I have not done this, but I am getting the same error. The traceback seems to think the issue is somewhere in my `forms.py`. My `forms.py` is below:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Indicator


def get_indicator_ids():
    ids = []
    indicator_objects = Indicator.objects.all()
    for indicator in indicator_objects:
        ids.append(indicator.id)
    return ids


class IndicatorDropDown(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IndicatorDropDown, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['indicators'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_indicator_ids())


class IndicatorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Indicator
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['creator']


class SearchForIndicatorMetaData(forms.Form):
    search_for_indicator_metadata = forms.IntegerField(label='Search for metadata by ID', max_value=999999999)
```

`forms.py` calls the model `Indicator`, however this has not changed from the last commit where it was working. All of my choice fields are tuples, and so should not throw this error. Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit - adding the model as well

```
class Indicator(models.Model):
    time_periods = (
        get_time_periods()
    )

    months = (
        get_months()
    )

    calculations = (
        get_calculations()
    )

    sex_ids = (
        get_all_sexes()
    )

    age_ids = (
        get_all_ages()
    )

    operands = (
       ('+', '+'),
       ('-', '-'),
       ('*', '*'),
       ('/', '/')
    )

    salt_options = get_salt_options_as_tuple()

    qof_data_choices = (
        ('qof-{}-prev-ach-exc-ms-prac.xlsx', 'Musculoskeletal group'),
        ('qof-{}-prev-ach-exc-neu-prac.xlsx', 'Mental health and neurology group'),
        ('qof-{}-prev-ach-exc-fer-obs-gyn-prac.xlsx', 'Fertility, obstetrics and gynaecology group'),
        ('qof-{}-prev-ach-exc-hd-prac.xlsx', 'High dependency and other long term conditions group'),
        ('qof-{}-prev-ach-exc-ls-prac.xlsx', 'Lifestyle group'),
        ('qof-{}-prev-ach-exc-resp-prac.xlsx', 'Respiratory group'),
        ('qof-{}-prev-ach-exc-cv-prac.xlsx', 'Cardiovascular group'),
        ('qof-{}-prac-dom-ach.xlsx', 'Achievement group'),
        ('qof-{}-prac-dom-exc.xlsx', 'Exclusion group'),
    )

    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    source_data_family = models.ForeignKey(IndicatorFamily, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    qof_source_data = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=qof_data_choices, blank=True)
    source_sheet = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    year_range = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    time_period = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=time_periods, blank=True)
    ageId = models.IntegerField(choices=age_ids, blank=True)
    sexId = models.IntegerField(choices=sex_ids)
    calculation = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=calculations, blank=True)
    rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    value_declared_independently = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    value_column_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    numerator_starts_with_financial_year = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    numerator = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    salt_numerator = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, choices=salt_options)
    salt_numerator_operand = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=operands, blank=True)
    salt_numerator_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, choices=salt_options)
    numerator_minus_not_caseness = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    iapt_q_m_variable_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    iapt_q_m_variable_a = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    iapt_q_m_variable_b = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    iapt_q_m_variable_type_denominator = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    iapt_q_m_variable_a_denominator = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    iapt_q_m_variable_b_denominator = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    denominator_starts_with_financial_year = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    denominator = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    denominator_minus_not_caseness = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    denominator_source_sheet = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    salt_denominator = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, choices=salt_options)
    salt_denominator_operand = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=operands, blank=True)
    salt_denominator_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, choices=salt_options)
    add_denominator_column = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    additional_denominator_column_starts_with_financial_year = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    adjust_denominator_for_person_years = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ccg_over_18_population_as_denominator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ccg_total_population_as_denominator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_count = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_percentage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ccg_to_stp = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    gp_to_upper_tier_la = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ccg_lookup_required = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    drop_depression = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    count_non_nulls = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    non_null_columns = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    drop_eng_row = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    months_to_quarter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    snapshot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    asterisk_as_two = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    denominator_2_equals_denominator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    do_not_suppress_small_numbers = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    numerator_is_num_minus_denom = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stp_is_average_not_sum = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mental_health_trust_geographies = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    filter_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
#    ld_denominator_source_file = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=qof_data_choices, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Edit 2 - updated traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\IndicatorAnalyserWebapp\Analyser\Indicators\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .views import (
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\IndicatorAnalyserWebapp\Analyser\Indicators\views.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .forms import IndicatorForm, SearchForIndicatorMetaData
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\IndicatorAnalyserWebapp\Analyser\Indicators\forms.py", line 19, in <module>
    class IndicatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 252, in __new__
    opts.field_classes)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 166, in fields_for_model
    formfield = f.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1873, in formfield
    return super(IntegerField, self).formfield(**defaults)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 872, in formfield
    defaults['choices'] = self.get_choices(include_blank=include_blank)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda37\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 802, in get_choices
    for choice, __ in choices:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Edit 3 - Added examples of functions being called from model

```
def get_months():
    months = (
        ('jan', 'January'),
        ('feb', 'February'),
        ('mar', 'March'),
        ('apr', 'April'),
        ('may', 'May'),
        ('jun', 'June'),
        ('jul', 'July'),
        ('aug', 'August'),
        ('sep', 'September'),
        ('oct', 'October'),
        ('nov', 'November'),
        ('dec', 'December')
    )
    return months


def get_time_periods():
    time_periods = (
        ('monthly', 'Monthly'),
        ('quarterly', 'Quarterly'),
        ('annual', 'Annual')
    )
    return time_periods


def get_calculations():
    calcs = (
        ('WILSON', 'Wilson'),
        ('BYAR', 'Byar')
    )
    return calcs
```

Comment: But choice fields need to be tuples of tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All of my choice fields are tuples, and so should not throw this error.

It throws an error, because you here added a field to your form with:

```
... = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_indicator_ids())
```

and the `get_indicator_ids()` indeed does *not* return a list of 2-tuples. It simply is a flat list of integers.

You can change the implementation of `get_indicator_ids`, but in fact here you want to make it possible to select `Indicator` objects if I understand it correctly. Then it is bitter to use a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), like:

```
class IndicatorDropDown(forms.Form):

    indicators = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Indicator.objects.all())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Willem Van Onsem. I have implemented these changes, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @RustyBrain: then there is likely still a field with choices that uses a flat list, instead of a list of 2-tuples.

Comment: @RustyBrain: you did remove the construction of the `ChoiceField` in the `__init__` function, right?

Comment: Yes, I did comment the whole Class out and replaced it with your suggestion.

Comment: @RustyBrain: it looks like there are still some `ChoiceField`s, etc. with flat lists/tuples as choices. Is the error still located at the `class IndicatorForm(forms.ModelForm):` (in the traceback)?

Comment: Yes it is, as far as I can see the traceback is the same. I have added the rest of the model to my question just in case the problem is in there.

Comment: @RustyBrain: can you edit your question and add the new traceback?

Comment: I've added the updated traceback now. Thanks for all your efforts!

Comment: @RustyBrain: and you did use `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Indicator.objects.all())`, right? So `ModelChoic...` and `queryset=...`?

Comment: @RustyBrain: based on the traceback, there is also a problem in your models (as far as I can see). Do all the `choices=...` produce iterables of 2-tuples? Like `get_time_periods`, `get_all_ages`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, they all return tuples. I did use the ModelChoiceField code.

Comment: @RustyBrain: tuples, or a tuple of *tuples*. The problem is not that these do (not) return tuples, the problem is that the *items* of the iterable should be 2-tuples as well. It might be useful to share (some) of these functions.

Comment: Yes they return tuples of tuples - I have added some examples in the question

Comment: Having gone through this again today I think there was a change to an API that I was using that was wrapping the data in a list - so it was a tuple of a list of a tuple that was causing the error. I think this suggestion was as close to an answer as other people will find useful. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 2):

`choices` should be in this format:

```
[
    (value_1, label_1),
    (value_2, label_2),
    ...
]
```

You'll need to modify your code to append items to the list in 2-tuple format:

```
ids.append((indicator.id, indicator.id))
```

Above, `indicator.id` is also the label for the choice. Label is what django displays to the user when selecting a choice. You should probably provide the name of the object instead of plain id.

---

**Note:** The other answer by Willem is a better solution for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As above, I've tried it out but still getting the same error